# ToPolarCoordinates not working with units

Tags: units, conversion

I am trying to convert some quantities with units from rectangular to polar coordinates (to get the magnitude and angle). It seems that **ToPolarCoordinates** command does not calculate the angle when units are present. Does anyone have a solution to this (other than removing the units)?

```
N1 = Quantity[1.0, "Newtons"];
N2 = Quantity[2.0, "Newtons"];
ToPolarCoordinates[{N1, N2}]
```

The output is:

[image]

```
M1 = 1.0;
M2 = 2.0;
ToPolarCoordinates[{M1, M2}]
```

The output is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether `ArcTan` of two quantities with compatible units *should* work by default, but you can certainly make it work yourself.

```
Unprotect[ArcTan];
ArcTan[q1_Quantity, q2_Quantity] := 
 ArcTan[QuantityMagnitude[q1], QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[q2, QuantityUnit[q1]]]]
Protect[ArcTan];

N1 = Quantity[1.0, "Newtons"];
N2 = Quantity[2.0, "Newtons"];
ToPolarCoordinates[{N1, N2}]

(* {Quantity[2.23607, "Newtons"], 1.10715} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is Mathematica cannot handle the units directly, so you need to extract the magnitudes, convert those magnitudes to polar, and reattach the units like so:

```
N1 = Quantity[1.0, "Newtons"];
N2 = Quantity[2.0, "Newtons"];

N1Value = QuantityMagnitude[N1];
N2Value = QuantityMagnitude[N2];

polarCoordinates = ToPolarCoordinates[{N1Value, N2Value}];

magnitude = Quantity[polarCoordinates[[1]], "Newtons"]
angle = Quantity[polarCoordinates[[2]], "Degrees"]*180/Pi

Out[10]= 2.23607 N
Out[11]= 63.4349 deg
```

You can change `angle` if you want `rad`.